# Bad result from Java modulo operator?

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-accuracy, modulo

I suspect this has been asked before, but can't seem to find a question that matches...

I'm using Scala, but I'm pretty sure this is just a Java problem... input values are doubles

```
println(28.0 / 5.6) 
println(28.0 % 5.6)
```

The result of these lines is

```
5.0 
1.7763568394002505E-15
```

Which means that Java is performing the division correctly, but for some reason getting the modulo wrong, since the modulo should be 0 for any division problem that resolves to a whole number...

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: You're doing float-math here. The divide doesn't give you "5" but gives you "something like 5.0". Theres not infinite precision. The modulo gives you the remainder, which is also subject to the same precission problem, and gives you something close-ish to 0. Within the precision you have, this rather close to the answer. ONly sollution is: don't do float-math is you aim for exact answers?

Comment: FWIW: C# yields the same results with doubles, so it's clearly not just a Java issue.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: It's not an "issue" with Java or C# at all. It's an issue with the OP's interpretation of the results :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thanks for clarifying. That's the point I was trying to make, but I didn't state it quite right. It's not "just a Java problem" as the OP states, but rather an indication of what happens when we try to force a binary calculator to give us binary results.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet -- okay, you just go and live in your own world where 56 * 5 is something other than 280 then -- the rest of us are living in this world where decimal math systems are supposed to be consistent

Comment: @Sam: You're not dealing with a decimal maths system, and you're not dealing with 56 - you're dealing with "the closest double to 5.6" which is very different indeed. If you keep trying to assert your views on the way floating point arithmetic *should* work on the rest of the world, you're going to be disappointed. It would be more productive for you to learn how binary floating point *actually* works, what you should avoid, and what the alternatives are. (BigDecimal in Java, for example.)

Comment: Imo this is only a problem if 1.7763e-15 isn't 'close enough to 0' for you, in which case you really need to use a lossless structure, like BigDecimal. If you're doing this for say... money, you definitely want to use BigDecimal.

Comment: Only amongst a group of programmers is it possible to ask a 3rd grade math problem and have grown adults tell you the correct answer is wrong. And if the workaround is to use a different data type like BigDecimal, then the appropriate answer is not "why would you want to do simple 3rd grade math?!", it's "use BigDecimal instead of double"

Comment: @Sam: A third grader would probably also claim that the upper case version of "i" is always "I". Sometimes as software engineers we need to know things about our systems which would surprise third-graders. And when something *does* surprise us, it's our duty to find out why rather than just to work around it - to avoid something similar in the future. Likewise when we see someone else being surprised, I view it as important to explain the whole situation to them - an answer of *just* "Use BigDecimal" would have been entirely inappropriate, IMO.

Comment: @Jon - I wasn't offended by your providing a more thorough explanation (as several people did)... what I was offended by was your assertion that it was wrong of me to expect decimal results from a decimal math system (double) and therefore it was simply a "user error". Insulting people's intelligence doesn't make them feel welcome. I know it's an IEEE standard - it's a bad standard. I'd seen it before in other languages like JavaScript (where there also was a simple solution), but there are languages in which you don't have to worry about unpredictable rounding errors in 3rd grade math ops.

Comment: @Sam: But `double` simply *isn't* a decimal math system. It's a binary math system. Once you know that, the rest is easy. And you don't need to take this into account in Java either, if you use the right type - but I *do* think it's reasonable to expect software engineers to know the fundamentals (not the details, but the fundamentals) of the types in the language they use. It's crucial that you understand that `double` *isn't* a decimal floating point type (unlike, say, `decimal` in C#). To me that's like knowing that a `String` is composed of characters, not bytes, and why that's important.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 5.0 just shows that the *precise* result as Java understands it is closer to 5.0 than it is to any other double. That doesn't mean the precise result of the operation is *exactly* 5.

Now when you ask for the modulus, you're able to down to a much finer level of detail, because the result isn't pinned to having the "5" part.

That's not a great explanation, but imagine you had a *decimal* floating point type with 4 digits of precision. What's the result of 1000 / 99.99 and 1000 % 99.99?

Well, the real result starts with 10.001001 - so you have to round that to 10.00. However, the remainder is 0.10, which you can express. So again, it *looks* like the division gives you a whole number, but it doesn't *quite*.

With that in mind, bear in mind that your literal of 5.6 is *actually* 5.5999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375. Now clearly 28.0 (which *can) be represented exactly divided by that number isn't exactly 5.

EDIT: Now if you perform the result with *decimal* floating point arithmetic using `BigDecimal`, the value really *is* exactly 5.6, and there are no problems:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("28.0");
        BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal("5.6");

        BigDecimal div = x.divide(y);
        BigDecimal rem = x.remainder(y);

        System.out.println(div); // Prints 5
        System.out.println(rem); // Prints 0.0
    }
}
```

Comment: More precisely, it's closer to 5.0 than any other double that can be represented in the default floating point precision of println.

Comment: @Nayuki: No, 5.0 is "as close to the theoretical result of the operation as any other double is". I didn't say that the 5.0 wasn't exactly 5 - I said the *precise result* wasn't 5. See the bottom part of my edited answer and you'll see what I mean...

Comment: @Nayuki Minase: In the calculation itself, there is a slight floating-point imprecision, but when you represent the calculated value as a Double with a whole number value, it loses the precision necessary to preserve this imprecision (weird, huh?). A double doesn't have enough bits to represent 5.000000000000001, so it will become 5.0 exactly. However, when the result of the calculation no longer includes the "5", that causes the 0.000000000000001 to appear. The `double` is capable of representing this now because it doesn't have to represent all the digits between the 5 and the 1.

Answer (score 3):

The result isn't actually 0, but it's pretty close( 0.00000000000000177635... ).  The problem is that some decimal numbers can't be represented exactly in binary, so that's where the issue is coming in; I'd suspect that the same result would be printed out in C/C++.

Comment: C/C++ gets around the issue by prohibiting `float` or `double` from being arguments to the modulus operator :)

Comment: Ah, did not realize that.  I've never actually had a reason to do it.

Comment: While C/C++ do not have a modulo operator applicable to floating-point types, they do have an equivalent function, remainder() for double, remainderf() for float. For the case at hand the output from the double version matches what Sam Dealey is seeing with Java: x= 2.8000000000000000e+001 (403c000000000000), y= 5.5999999999999996e+000 (4016666666666666), res= 1.7763568394002505e-015 (3ce0000000000000). As pointed out by other posters, the issue is that 5.6 is not exactly representable in a double. The result of remainder() itself is always exact.

Answer (score 2):

#### Arithmetic

First of all, the decimal number 5.6 cannot be represented exactly in binary floating-point. It is rounded to the exact binary fraction 3152519739159347/2<sup>49</sup>.

The fact that 28.0 / 5.6 = 5.0 is because 5.0 is the closest `double` number to the true result, where the true result is 5.0000000000000003172065784643....

As for 28.0 % 5.6, the true result is exactly 1/2<sup>49</sup>, which is approximately 1.776 × 10<sup>−15</sup>, so the calculation is correctly rounded.

#### Workarounds

Why do you need a workaround? For most applications, keeping the very slightly wrong result is fine. Are you concerned about displaying "pretty" results?

If you need absolutely precise arithmetic, then you will need to use some implementation of BigFraction.

#### Further reading

The topic of floating-point caveats has been covered in a variety of articles:

- http://floating-point-gui.de/
- http://www.petebecker.com/js/js200006.html
- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

(In decreasing order of reader-friendliness.)

Comment: I'm creating a ruler for an art application and using the modulo to determine an index in an array to find the height of the mark on the ruler -- if it doesn't find a height with a modulo value of zero it returns -1 and produces an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error, so yeah, it's not a question of "pretty", it's functional

Comment: Can you rewrite your math code so that you only do integer arithmetic? For example instead of 28 % 5.6, how about shifting everything left by one place and calculating 280 % 56?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for check if double value is divisible by another using modulo operator:

```
public class DoubleOperation
{
    public static final double EPSILON = 0.000001d;

    public static boolean equals(double val1, double val2)
    {
        return (Math.abs(val1 - val2) < EPSILON);
    }

    public static boolean divisible(double dividend, double divisor)
    {
        double divisionRemainder = dividend % divisor;
        return (equals(divisionRemainder, 0.0d) || equals(divisionRemainder, divisor));
    }
}
```